# Add URL Rewrite Rule .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've installed a Wordpress plugin that makes my website to a static one. The plugin is called "Simply Static".

Now I have a static version of my website here: http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/static/

But my visitors should not see the whole url, i want them just to see http://example.com 
or e.g.: http://example.com/contact/ instead of http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/static/contact/

However I can't seem to modify the htaccess to rewrite this.

I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^/ /wp-content/uploads/static/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: That is not the intention of the plugin. The plugin author says to host wordpress with caching OR host wordpress on your local dev server (your own computer) and push only the static site on the web. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/use-as-static-website/

Comment: I know that. Still I want to do it differently.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite from `/` to `/wp-content/uploads/static`, you just use

```
RewriteRule !^wp-content/uploads/static /wp-content/uploads/static%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Note the following

- the pattern never starts with a slash in a directory context (e.g. .htaccess)
- `%{REQUEST_URI}` already contains a leading slash
- no [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag